# Limit annotation target only to methods with another annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I want to restrict an annotation to be applied only to methods that have another annotation. For example only allow `@A` on methods that has `@B`. I don't see there is any direct way to do this with the `@Target` annotation type. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered reflection?

Comment: @pm-77-1 I can do that validation at runtime with reflection. But by intention is to enforce this at compile time.

Comment: Could you encapsulate the intention of `@A` as an element of `@B`? That would seem make more sense if these should be coupled together. Unless you don't have control over the definition of `@B`.

Comment: No, I do not have control over `@B`. That comes from a library.

Comment: I think you should write your own annotation processor.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of no language defined mechanism which could be used to prevent placement an annotation except when another annotation was present.  Java annotations do accept the @Target meta-annotation, which can be used to restrict the annotation to particular locations.  That seems to be the closest thing that can be done.

As others have noted, you would need to extend annotations processing to add this capability.  I imagine you could, with perhaps not a small amount of work, add this sort of extension to a development environment such as Eclipse.